# An efficient probabilistic algorithm that gets a natural number N and returns a random number R in range 0<=R<=N using a coin toss

Tags: algorithm, random, coin-flipping, probabilistic-programming

i get a natural number N (0,1,2..) and i need to use coin tosses to get a random number R that will appear in the range 0<=R<=N,
i am trying to figure out how many tosses i'll need to make it works?

Comment: With `k` tosses you can easily generate a random number uniformly at random in range `[0, 2**k)`. You just need to choose `k` such that `2**k > N`. Here I used `**` to note exponent.

Comment: so if my N=5 then i'll need 2^k > 5 tosses?

Comment: Yes. And you can see that k=2 is not enough (`2**2 == 4`) but k=3 is enough (`2**3 == 8`). So you toss 3 times. Use the tosses to flip bits of a binary number (heads = 1, tails = 0). That gives you a number between 0 and 7. If you get 6 or 7, then toss again.

Comment: Note the reason I am using symbol `**` and not `^` is because `^` is used to mean "bitwise xor" in many programming languages, so although in some context it might "obviously" mean exponent, it's not always so obvious and in fact can be really ambiguous.

Comment: The best answer depends on whether or not you can maintain state between calls and want to minimize total coin tosses over time, or if you need each call to be independently efficient.  Also on whether you need a truly even distribution, or a practically even distribution will do.  Also, I assume you mean 0 <= R < N, and that R must be an integer?

Comment: @Stef Ok i got it! thanks

Comment: @MattTimmermans you're right it depends, but the only note that i got is "Tossing a coin takes one unit of time", and yes R is an int.